# Read an object literal from a file and evaluate it without using an external library in AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I have a file with an object literal like so:

```
[
    {
        name: "ab c",
        windows: [
            {
                one   : 0,
                two: 0,
                three       : 12,
                four    : 6
            },
            {
                one   : 0,
                two: 6,
                three       : 12,
                four    : 6
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        name: "x y z",
        windows: [
            {
                one   : 0,
                two: 0,
                three       : 12,
                four    : 6
            },
            {
                one   : 0,
                two: 6,
                three       : 12,
                four    : 6
            }
        ]
    }

]
```

I know I can read the file as a string into a variable like so:

```
data := FileRead(A_ScriptDir "\file.cfg")
```

What I want to do is evaluate the string to a variable so it's an object I can access in AHK 2.0.

So I should be able to do something like:

```
MsgBox data[0].name
```

But I do not want to use any external libraries.

Is this possible?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you want help (you only asked a yes/no question, and yes it is possible). Do you know how to parse the string you save into an `array` or `dict` elements? String manipulations are easy in AHK and there is RegEx support as well (not sure if that counts as external though).

Comment: We should call them "JSON" and not "object literal", because we are in the realm of AHK and not JS; There is no built in JSON parsing in AHK.

Comment: What I have above is an AHK object literal, right? What I have will work fine if I added to an AHK script. I just want a way to read/write that from a text file.

Comment: Ah you are right, and the keys are missing the double quote wrapping required by JSONs too. Sorry it's my mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we *should* call it json, but, a little simple string manipulation as follows permits native ahk syntax without the json.ahk external library. Take a look:

```
Str2 := [{"name":"ab c","windows":[{"one":0,"two":0,"three":12,"four":6},{"one":0,"two":6,"three":12,"four":6}]},{"name":"x y z","windows":[{"one":0,"two":0,"three":12,"four":6},{"one":0,"two":6,"three":12,"four":6}]}]

MsgBox % Str2.1.name . " " . Str2.2.name
MsgBox % Str2.1.windows.1.two . " " . Str2.1.windows.2.two
```

And you should get the picture.

Comment: Yes. I am familiar with this. My issue is I want to read/write it from a file.